# Transfer/Migrate specific apps including settings etc to a new Mac

Tags: applications, macos, migration

I did a clean install upgrade to OS X Yosemite (from Mavericks).

Prior to doing that I backed up my entire hard disk using a disk cloner (Carbon Copy Cloner in my case)

Is there a way I can transfer a few specific apps from my previous installation (including settings, licenses etc) to the new one?

Answer (score 1):

mackup does this:

https://github.com/lra/mackup

I don't have personal experience with it, but i've heard great things. Bear in mind you should check the list of software currently supported by it before you install.

Comment: regarding apps to transfer, you could create a cask in homebrew and host it on dropbox or your cloud of choice.

Comment: Thanks... this sounds promising. I am not very experienced using Homebrew (have just used it once). Can you elaborate your answer a little bit more?

Comment: first check out **[homebrew](http://brew.sh/)**